# How to deallocate an element in a vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, memory-management

So I have a vector of pointers like so:

```
vector<Example*> ve;
```

I fill this vector with pointers like this

```
Example* e = new Example();
ve.push_back(e)
```

But when I want to remove them, how do I assure they get deallocated?
Is this enough?

```
ve.erase(ve.begin() + 1)
delete ve[1]
```

Comment: One thing to consider: do you need pointers at all? You do if the objects are of different (polymorphic) types; or if they are impossible or prohibitively expensive to move; or if the vector doesn't "own" them (which it does here, since you want to deallocate them on removal). Otherwise, consider `vector<Example>` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to do it the other way round, of course:

```
delete ve[1];
ve.erase(ve.begin() + 1);
```

However, it's vastly more preferable to use smart pointers (such as `std::unique_ptr`) instead of raw pointers when expressing ownership.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the pointers **before** erasing the vector:

```
for (vector<Example *>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
    delete *it;
}

vec.clear();
```

Comment: Use `vec.clear()` instead of `vec.erase(vec.begin(), vec.end())`.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Fair enough, fixed.